# why p1 misses it first deadline? Rate monotonic scheduling

Tags: process-scheduling, real-time

I understand that rate monotonic scheduling assigns a priority to a process based on the periodicity of the tasks it generates and the process with the shortest inter-task period has the highest priority but i am confused as to why in this particular scenario p1 will miss its first deadline?

[image]
PS Sorry but english isn't my first language

Comment: P2 is scheduled before P1, and by the time that P1T1 finishes, it is past its deadline (which is perhaps the beginning of P1T2).

Comment: Two concurrent P1T1 events may miss a deadline if there is a process that consumes twice the time of T1. "Race conditional failure". This leads to defining a real time OS with interrupts that handle critical short tasks and stacks longer term tasks using the shortest time interval for detecting occurence of each tasks so that events are not missed but then enough processing power must be available to ,prevent stack overflow.